# Are computer ports part of the network level of part of the operating system level?

Tags: port-forwarding

I know that computer systems can communicate one with the other via **ports**, say from port 80 of computer system X to port 80 of computer system Y.

Are computer ports part of the network (hardware) level of part of the operating system (software) level?

---

The purpose of the question is to understand, If I have one of the following situations:

- A non virtual machine with two or more operating systems
- A non virtual machine with say, Windows on which I have established a virtual machine with say Linux

In both cases, would *ports already occupied by one system* won't be free to the other system?
I guess that if ports are hardware than yes, but if they are software and could be virtual themselves than no.

Answer (score -1):

Computer ports are operating system level also considered as  application layer.

For example consider port TCP -3389 used for RDP access . When computer A wants to take Remote RDP access of Computer B .So in this scenario initially RDP 3389 port should be opened at destination system that is in computer B and further port should opened through network path connectivity from computer A to computer B .

So concluding services on specific port should be in listening mode to get specific port opened at computer or server level . It is operating system level only .